# Does this database need normalized?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I am creating an application in Oracle Apex which will be used to audit a process.

- Data for this audit is based almost entirely on an ETL from our EHR that I wrote.
- Data for this audit comes from an already normalized database
- The only user-input will be comments about the process and changing some Y/N fields

My question: If the data for my system is solely based on already normalized data, is there any reason to replicate that normalization in my database (adding to development time and complexity)?

Right now I feel like the cons of normalizing outweigh the pros.

Thanks

Comment: yes - it should be normalized.  you don't describe some very important things: like is this all in the same database?  if so, then just add on your audit tables with an appropriate set of foreign keys - all is good.

Comment: @Randy - yes this is all in the same database, that was an approach I am thinking of

Answer (score 0):

In any normalization process, the first step is to test to see which, if any, of the normal forms is being violated.  Your case is no exception.  If no normal form is being violated, you're done!

It's conceivable that the user inputs might depart from some normal form.  It's conceivable that you might discover some departure from normal forms in the input data that has gone undetected.

Even if you do find departures from full normalization, you need to compare the cost of living with a partially denormalized design and the costs of producing and maintaining a fully normalized one.